# How to mock a createConnection function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm working on a TypeScript project and I have a class called `read` that interacts with a MySQL database using the `createConnection` function from `mysql/promise`. The class has a method `read` which performs a SELECT query on a specified table and returns the results.

Here's a simplified version of the class:

```
class read {
  private options: ConnectionOptions;
  constructor(options: ConnectionOptions) {
    this.options = options;
  }
  
  read = async (table_name: string): Promise<any> => {
    const connection: Connection = await createConnection(this.options);
    let readQuery = `SELECT * FROM ${table_name}`;
    const [results] = await connection.query<RowDataPacket[]>(readQuery);
    return results;
  };
}
```

I want to write unit tests for this class, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to mock the database connection and the query execution. I'm using Jest for testing.

Could someone please guide me on how to mock the createConnection function and the subsequent query execution, so that I can test the read method in isolation? I'm looking for a way to simulate different scenarios such as successful query execution, empty results, or even error cases.

Comment: Don't. For two reasons: 1. that's an interface you don't own; and 2. creating the connection inside the class means they're coupled. You _could_ invert the dependency, but still probably shouldn't be injecting a mock connection. Mock a _facade_ that exposes relevant methods (think: repository), then test the facade at an integration level.

Comment: So how you would recommend me to test this class?